# How to generate current date in ISO 8601 format in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I need to generate a string with the current time in the same format as the following: `20130524T000000Z`

The example is a timestamp for `Fri, 24 May 2013 00:00:00 GMT`.

How would I do that? Is there a way to do it without external packages?

Answer (score 8):

**Updated 2016-07-18**

Elixir [1.3](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/tag/v1.3.0) and up has support for this natively:

```
iex> DateTime.utc_now() |> DateTime.to_iso8601()
"2016-07-18T21:49:08.132428Z"
```

**Original 2015-12-01** *(with version differences added 2016-07-18, thanks @sebastian_k)*

You could use the excellent [timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) library if you didn't mind using an external library:

[*timex 1.x*](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/releases/tag/1.0.0) ([docs](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/tree/1.0.0#formatting-a-datetime-as-an-iso-8601-string))

```
iex> Timex.Date.local |> Timex.DateFormat.format("{ISOz}")
{:ok, "2015-12-01T09:40:44.716Z"}
```

[*timex 2.x*](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/releases/tag/2.0.0) ([docs](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/2.0.0/docs/Basic%20Usage.md#formatting-a-datetime-as-an-iso-8601-string))

```
iex> Timex.DateTime.local() |> Timex.format("{ISOz}")
{:ok, "2015-12-01T09:40:44.716Z"}
```

[*timex 3.x*](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/releases/tag/3.0.0) ([docs](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/3.0.0/docs/Basic%20Usage.md#formatting-a-datetime-as-an-iso-8601-string))

```
iex> Timex.now() |> Timex.format("{ISO:Extended:Z}")
{:ok, "2015-12-01T09:40:44.716417ZZ"}
```

Comment: As of v3 (July '16), this should now be `Timex.now |> Timex.format("{ISO:Extended:Z}")`, or `Timex.now("Europe/Amsterdam") |> Timex.format("{ISO:Extended:Z}")`.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to do with the following code:

```
{{yy, mm, dd}, {hh, mi, ss}} = :calendar.universal_time
"~.4.0w~.2.0w~.2.0wT~.2.0w~.2.0w~.2.0wZ"
|> :io_lib.format([yy, mm, dd, hh, mi, ss])
|> IO.iodata_to_binary
```

but perhaps there is a better way?