# generate iso8601 string without the time

Tags: date, elixir, iso8601

As per the answers/comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016207/how-to-generate-current-date-in-iso-8601-format-in-elixir) I know how to generate an iso860 datetime string:

```
iex> Timex.now() |> Timex.format("{ISO:Extended:Z}")
{:ok, "2015-12-01T09:40:44.716499ZZ"}
```

However is there a best practice way to generate the above without the time?
So far I have:

```
iex> to_string(Timex.today) <> "Z"
```

Comment: So you want the date + "Z"? You could do `|> Timex.format!("{ISOdate}Z")`.

Comment: Absolute legend - didn't know you could include characters in the quotes.

Comment: @ Dogbert can't vote a comment as the answer though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Timex's format strings allow arbitrary text outside the braces, so if you just want to add `Z` to `{ISOdate}` (as clarified in comments), you can format with `{ISOdate}Z`:

```
iex(1)> Timex.today |> Timex.format!("{ISOdate}Z")
"2017-03-27Z"
```